# Scrapy gzip errors

Tags: scrapy, gzip, middleware

I seem to be getting gzip errors with Scrapy quite a lot. For example:

```
2016-11-04 16:18:25 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.laithwaites.co.uk/wines/Grenache/_/N-1z141xy?icamp=nav-browse-grenache&No=0#page-1>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/my/proj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1185, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/path/to/my/proj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 53, in process_response
    spider=spider)
  File "/path/to/my/proj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/httpcompression.py", line 30, in process_response
    decoded_body = self._decode(response.body, encoding.lower())
  File "/path/to/my/proj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/httpcompression.py", line 46, in _decode
    body = gunzip(body)
  File "/path/to/my/proj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/gz.py", line 37, in gunzip
    chunk = read1(f, 8196)
  File "/path/to/my/proj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/gz.py", line 21, in read1
    return gzf.read(size)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 261, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 312, in _read
    uncompress = self.decompress.decompress(buf)
error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid distance too far back
```

When I later try to fetch this URL in a shell there is no problem.

I read elsewhere that maybe removing `httpcompression` middleware could be a solution, but I'm worried in case that has other implications.

Comment: `COMPRESSION_ENABLED=False` will make scrapy not ask for compressed HTTP response. It will download bigger responses over the network, but it should not cause anything bad.

Comment: Yeah, this is an OK temporary fix, but ideally, I'd like to benefit from compression (we have lots of data to download often).

Comment: You can set `COMPRESSION_ENABLED=False` as `custom_settings` just for that spider. I cannot reproduce the error myself (with a simple CrawlSpider follow-all-links on www.laithwaites.co.uk). If it's for more than just this website, maybe it has to do with your setup (some proxies involved perhaps?)